# Possible to buy a game that you get free with Playtation Plus?

Tags: ps3, psn

I was wondering if it is possible to buy a game that you get free with Playtation Plus?
Because I wanted to buy Borderlands 2 for  €9.99 durning the January sale permanently, so I coud play it when my plus+ subscription expires.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://worthplaying.com/article/2013/4/15/editorials/88859/ it sounds like you can call customer support to have them remove your PS+ license for Borderlands and then you could purchase your own license.